# FOR JSON PATH - produce array of numbers, not objects

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with just one column which I am trying to convert to a `.json` file.

The table is formatted like below

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

The desired JSON output looks like this:

```
{
    "ids": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
}
```

The closest I have come is with the following code

```
SELECT
    id
FROM 
    table 
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('ids')
```

Which returns

```
{
    "ids": [ { "id": "1" },
             { "id": "2" },
             { "id": "3" } 
           ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID])
VALUES (1), (2), (3);

SELECT JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG('"' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + '"', ','), ']')) AS ids
FROM @DataSource
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

[image]